# React Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `render` method of one of my React components I have the following code, in which I decide whether or not to render a form.

```
{ this.state.hideForm == false
?    <ListAddition classification={this.props.data} />
: null}
```

However, I am getting the following error on the second line of the code:

```
Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of null
```

I am certain that the `this.props` variable has been correctly instantiated. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you add your _render_ method? And also add you react vertion

Comment: My `render` method is really large and I'm not sure if the rest of the code is very relevant.

Comment: My bet would be that you have a react component that renders nothing. Then fix would be: instead of rendering `null`, do not render the component (fix in parent component), or (dirty solution), render an empty/ hidden component.